# App Delegate : Service call coming back from background

Tags: ios, swift, background, appdelegate

I want to call a web service whenever application coming back in the foreground. I am calling it from `didBecomeActive()`.

What's the best way to handle it and pass data to **Root view controller**?

Comment: Is root view controller always going to be the same view controller or is there a specific controller you always want to pass the data to?

Comment: It will be the same. I will fill or update a singleton object from Root & will use it throughout the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data you want to pass is always going to the same view controller you should instead set the observer in that view controller instead of app delegate. This way you won't need to pass any data in the first place.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default
          .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(activityHandler(_:)),
                       name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }


    @objc func activityHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
      //Call your web service here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. let me try this one. I will check & let you know.

Comment: Thanks, @Cameron Porter. It's working for me. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to hear, could you please mark the question as answered since it answered your question? :P

Comment: Yeah, sure mate :D. BTW How's the question? ;) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. Get rootViewController and pass the data, handle it.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    // 1
    let rootVC1 = self.window?.rootViewController

    // 2
    let rooVC2 = application.windows.first?.rootViewController

    ...
    /*
       pass data to rootVC1 or rootVC2 
    */
}
```